# Only enumerate files in folders with specific names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder structure and files like this:

```
 - doe-john
   - inbox
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - sent
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - notes
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - contacts
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
 - doe-jane
   - inbox
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - sent
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - notes
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
   - contacts
      - 1.
      - 2.
      - 3.
```

I only want to enumerate the files from the `inbox` and `sent` folders within each main folder. I know how to enumerate all of the files like so:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_level_folder):
    for fn in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, fn), 'r') as f:
            pass  # do something
```

I would presume that I would do it something like this, but I'm not quite sure how to do this correctly:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_level_folder):
    for dir in dirs:
        if dir.lower() == "inbox" or dir.lower() == "sent":
            for fn in files:
                with open(os.path.join(root, fn), 'r') as f:
                    pass  # do something
```

But this still just enumerates all the files. How do I *only* enumerate the files in the folders with the specified folder names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `root` and `dirs`. `root` is the "current directory" at each level; `dirs` is a *list of directories visible at this level*.

Your current code processes all files in each directory, once per visible subdirectory. What you want is to see whether your current directory is `inbox` or `sent`, and only then do your processing.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_level_folder):
    if root.lower().endswith("inbox") or root.lower().endswith("sent"):
        for fn in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, fn), 'r') as f:
                pass  # do something
```

---

You can also set `topdown=True` in your `walk` call, and then modify which subdirectories you want to walk into.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_level_folder, topdown=True):
    if root != top_level_folder:
        # only recurse into level 3+ directories with the desired names
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in ['inbox', 'sent']]
    if root.lower().endswith("inbox") or root.lower().endswith("sent"):
        for fn in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, fn), 'r') as f:
                pass  # do something
```

---

However, I find that option to be a little bit ugly (especially since you need a special case at the top level to avoid skipping `/doe-john`, etc.). In your particular case, since there are only two directories you want to look at and they're only one level down, I wouldn't use `walk` at all:

```
for person in os.listdir(top_level_folder):
    inbox = os.path.join(top_level_folder, person, 'inbox')
    sent = os.path.join(top_level_folder, person, 'sent')

    for file in os.listdir(inbox):
        pass # Do something

    for file in os.listdir(sent):
        pass # Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `dirs` returned from `os.walk()` if you use the `topdown=True` option. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again. Modifying *dirnames* when *topdown* is `False` is ineffective, because in bottom-up mode the directories in *dirnames* are generated before *dirpath* itself is generated.

Comment: I would upvote this too but it will not let me. I do not have enough rep, sorry.