# Selecting specific files in specific folders python os.walk

Tags: python, file, os.walk

I have 20 subfolders in my Source folder. I want to do an os.walk on just 8 of those folders and select just the files with a txt extension. Is this possible?

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Source'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Yes: ignore the others.  What’s your real question?

Comment: @DavisHerring I added my code in my question. But the code I use gets all the txt files from all the 20 subfolders. How do ignore 12 of the 20 subfolders?

Comment: You have the names both of the ones that exist and (necessarily) the ones you care about.  Are you concerned with the *efficiency* of ignoring them (for which there is an answer)?

Comment: @DavisHerring Well there is allot of useless stuff in the 12 subfolders which I want to ignore. I mean like they are useless for this script because I dont need them, however I cant delete them also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only enumerate files in folders with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872608/only-enumerate-files-in-folders-with-specific-names)

Comment: No, it did not solve it:( I need os.walk to literately walk through all the 8 subfolders and check if they have subfolders and if they also got sub subfolders etc. And from that all take the .txt extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive list of directories like this:

```
import os
dirs_positive_list = ['dir_1', 'dir_2']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Source'):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in dirs_positive_list]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

This will only process txt files which are present in `dir_1` and `dir_2`

This in-place edit of rids is described in the help of `os.walk`

Or use a negative list, a so called 'black list':

```
import os
black_list = ['dir_3'] # insert your folders u do not want to process here

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Source'):
    print(dirs)
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in black_list]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: I tried this out and its seems pretty okay. However, it stopt directly after it finds a txt file in dir_1 or dir_2. What about if dir_1 and dir_2 also got subfolders? You know what I mean, I need it to go endless through all the ``dirs_positive_list`` including subfolders or sub-subfolders...

Comment: Ah okay - use a negative list in this case. I will adapt my answer

Comment: And where does Dir3 supose to stand...What you mean by negative list?

Comment: Also known as a `Black List`. This is a list with folders you do not want to process. Only Top Level Folder need to be put in here

Comment: So you are telling me to insert the 12 folders I do not want to process in the ``dirs_neg_list`` ?

Comment: Yes, I also changed the name of the list to `black_list`

Comment: Thank you bro! appreciate your help, you deserve more then 'new contributor'

Comment: I now have If file endswith(). I also want to add if the files is empty I need to skip it. Is that possible?